# How do I add Javascript attributes to ASP.NET RadioButtonList items?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, radiobuttonlist

I'm trying to add some **onmouseover** and **onmouseout** attributes to any of the <input>, <td>, or <label> elements for each **ListItem** of a **RadioButtonList**.  How do I do this?  Here's what I've tried.  This does not work...

ASPX File...

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonListPaymentFrequency"
    runat="server"
    RepeatDirection="Vertical"
    RepeatLayout="Table"
    RepeatColumns="1" />
```

VB Code Behind...

```
Dim ListItemOneTimeOnly As New ListItem("One-Time Only", "1")
ListItemOneTimeOnly.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "ddrivetip('Example: $300 total amount paid one-time means 1 payment of $300.')")
ListItemOneTimeOnly.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "hideddrivetip()")
RadioButtonListPaymentFrequency.Items.Add(ListItemOneTimeOnly)

Dim ListItemMonthly As New ListItem("Monthly", "12")
ListItemMonthly.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "ddrivetip('Example: $300 total amount paid monthly means 12 payments of $25.')")
ListItemMonthly.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "hideddrivetip()")
RadioButtonListPaymentFrequency.Items.Add(ListItemMonthly)

Dim ListItemQuarterly As New ListItem("Quarterly", "4")
ListItemQuarterly.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "ddrivetip('Example: $300 total amount paid quarterly means 4 payments of $75.')")
ListItemQuarterly.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "hideddrivetip()")
RadioButtonListPaymentFrequency.Items.Add(ListItemQuarterly)

Dim ListItemSemiannually As New ListItem("Semiannually", "2")
ListItemSemiannually.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "ddrivetip('Example: $300 total amount paid monthly means 2 payments of $150.')")
ListItemSemiannually.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "hideddrivetip()")
RadioButtonListPaymentFrequency.Items.Add(ListItemSemiannually)
```

Generated HTML...

```
<table id="RadioButtonListPaymentFrequency" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="RadioButtonListPaymentFrequency_0" name="RadioButtonListPaymentFrequency" value="1" type="radio">
                <label for="RadioButtonListPaymentFrequency_0">One-Time Only</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="RadioButtonListPaymentFrequency_1" name="RadioButtonListPaymentFrequency" value="12" type="radio">
                <label for="RadioButtonListPaymentFrequency_1">Monthly</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="RadioButtonListPaymentFrequency_2" name="RadioButtonListPaymentFrequency" value="4" type="radio">
                <label for="RadioButtonListPaymentFrequency_2">Quarterly</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="RadioButtonListPaymentFrequency_3" name="RadioButtonListPaymentFrequency" value="2" type="radio">
                <label for="RadioButtonListPaymentFrequency_3">Semiannually</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Unless you use a [workaround](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q309338), or [subclass](https://web.archive.org/web/20210612110658/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091405-1.aspx) RadioButtonList. I'd personally just use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) to attach the event handlers.